# hidden attribute [hidden] in angular2 gets fired after a second hence showing element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-directives

I'm using [hidden] attribute in my app to hide some elements based on a certain condition. The scenario is, I have a div where I show results and I have a div where I show text "No results". Both divs have conditional [hidden] property applied to them. The Ideal scenario is, When page loads and results comes from server, there should be no "No Results" div displaying on the page and when there is no result from server, there should be test "No Results". But the problem is when page loads, it takes a second to load the results from server and for that 1 second the 2nd div is displayed saying "No results". The this occurs every time I refresh the page. I want to prevent this behavior i.e. I want a clean page and after data comes from server I want to display Results or "No Results" data on the page but right now I'm confused in how to achieve this. Any help?

Comment: some code might help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[hidden]`, better solution would be to use `ngIf` with `else` [syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else):

```
<div *ngIf="data |async; else elseBlock">Results</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>No Results</ng-template>
```